# ASP.NET TimeLine Control

Tags: .net, asp.net, controls, servercontrols, timeline

I am looking for a free control to display events in a to-scale-timeline.

I couldn't get [TimeLine.NET](http://timelinenet.codeplex.com/) to work.

Is there anything else I could try?

#### EDIT

Any flash or javascript solution would be fine as long as I can put data into it from a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using DayPilot?

http://www.daypilot.org/demo/Lite/SchedulerMonth.aspx

If you don't need multiple resources on the vertical axis, you can stuff everything into a single row and it will line up automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what your looking for but I've used googles [annotated time line](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html) to display something similar.

Comment: That's pretty cool, but I don't really need a series with varying values.

Answer (score 0):

OP requested a timeline without varying y-axis values, so instead of using annotated timeline as mentioned previously, you could use google's standard timeline:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline